# Паралакс при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

как сделать плавное смещение блока как в [примере](https://s-sd.ru/files/simple-effect-parallax-to-image/index.html)

```js
jQuery(".list-product .card").mousemove(
function(e){
var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
var xPos = e.pageX - offset.left;
var yPos = e.pageY - offset.top;
var mouseXPercent = Math.round(xPos / jQuery(this).width() * 100);
var mouseYPercent = Math.round(yPos / jQuery(this).height() * 100);
jQuery(this).children('.data-content').each(
function(){
var diffX = jQuery('.list-product .item').width() - jQuery(this).width();
var diffY = jQuery('.list-product .item').height() - jQuery(this).height();
var myX = -25 - diffX * (mouseXPercent / 1500);
var myY = 25 + diffY * (mouseYPercent / 1080);
var cssObj = {
'left': myX + 'px',
'top': myY + 'px'
}
jQuery(this).animate({left: myX, top: myY},{duration: 50, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
});
});
```

```css
.list-product {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    padding: 50px 0 120px; }
    .list-product .item {
      padding: 0 30px;
      max-width: 25%;
      -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
          -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
              flex-basis: 25%;
      height: 100%; }
      .list-product .item .card {
        height: 185px;
        position: relative;
        border: 3px solid #000; }
        .list-product .item .card .data-content {
          position: absolute;
          top: 25px;
          left: -25px;
          right: 0; }
          .list-product .item .card .data-content .data-img {
            padding-bottom: 185px;
            width: -webkit-calc(100% - 25px);
            width: calc(100% - 25px);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover; }
          .list-product .item .card .data-content h2 {
            margin: 25px 0 0;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-transform: uppercase; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-product">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="data-content" style="left: -23.86px; top: 20.7787px;">
         <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/194708/80fd536d-1d43-4e1a-91d0-be10c85a18b9/s280)"></div>
         <h2>срезанные цветы</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="data-content" style="left: -23.824px; top: 23.2157px;">
         <div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/194708/80fd536d-1d43-4e1a-91d0-be10c85a18b9/s280)"></div>
         <h2>горшочные растения</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let $prlx = $('#prlx'),
  $img = $prlx.find('img');
  
  $img.offset({
    'top': -($img.height() / 2) + ($prlx.height() / 2),
    'left': -($img.width() / 2) + ($prlx.width() / 2)
  });
  
  let startY = $img.offset().top,
    startX = $img.offset().left,
    stepY = ($img.height() - $prlx.height()) / 2,
    stepX = ($img.width() - $prlx.width()) / 2;
    
  $prlx.on('mousemove', function (el) {
    $img.offset({
      'top': startY + (stepY - el.pageY),
      'left': startX + (stepX - el.pageX)
    });
  });
```

```css
#prlx{width:600px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;position:relative}
#prlx img{position:absolute}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prlx"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ktlQrO2Sifg/maxresdefault.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Хороший, добротный ответ (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Не смог разобраться с вашим вариантом, могу что-то такое предложить:

```js
let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.data-img')];
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  images.forEach(i => {
    let hw = i.clientWidth/2;
    let hh = i.clientHeight/2;
    let x = i.offsetLeft + hw - e.clientX;
    let y = i.offsetTop + hh - e.clientY;
    if (Math.abs(x)>hw || Math.abs(y)>hh)
      return;
    i.style.backgroundPosition = (50-x/5) + "% " + (50-y/2) + "%"
  });
});
```

```css
.data-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: 66ms;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/194708/80fd536d-1d43-4e1a-91d0-be10c85a18b9/s280)"></div>
<div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/194708/80fd536d-1d43-4e1a-91d0-be10c85a18b9/s280)"></div>
<div class="data-img" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/194708/80fd536d-1d43-4e1a-91d0-be10c85a18b9/s280)"></div>
```